# Field access in Groovy for super class

Tags: groovy

In Groovy there is an `@` operator which enables direct field access. However it looks like it won't work for fields declared in super class. Consider two **Java** (not Groovy) classes:

```
class Entity {
  private Long id;

  Long getId() {
    return id;
  }
}

class User extends Entity {
}
```

Then invoking direct access in Groovy

```
User user = new User();
user.@id = 1L
```

ends up with exception: `groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: id for class User`

When I try to use standard access `user.id = 1L` I get `groovy.lang.ReadOnlyPropertyException: Cannot set readonly property: id for class User`

Is there any option to access field declared in super class?

Comment: You can access it without `@`, why you need direct access?

Comment: I have no setter for id

Comment: You have, because it was generated for you.

Comment: @JBaruch Java classes

Comment: So what does `user.id = 1L` give you?

Comment: @tim_yates I've added this case to my question

Comment: Ah right yeah without reflection hacking, you can't make a read-only property writable

Comment: It works when field is declared as protected

Comment: If you can change the Entity class, you should create a setter instead of relying on reflection//accessing protected field

Comment: I skipped the usecase which I thing was mistake. I don't want to expose id write in production code - just looking for solution to set it in tests (Spock)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would probably need to declare the property as protected instead:

```
class Entity {
  protected Long id;

  Long getId() {
    return id * 2;
  }
}

class User extends Entity {
}

User user = new User();
user.@id = 1L

assert user.@id == 1L
assert user.id == 2L
```

This is a modified example for the direct access field operator.

Answer (score 6):

You can access via regular Java reflection but I'm not sure how to make this more "Groovy".

```
User user = new User()
fields = user.getClass().superclass.declaredFields
idField = fields[0]
idField.accessible = true
idField.set(user, 2L)
println idField.get(user)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm surprised I haven't seen a more "Groovy" solution to this.  Disappointing.  Best I can do is remove some 'set' and 'get' prefixes and some parens.  REALLY?!!!

Comment: Only this solution worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Private fields can't be accessed from the children classes (they aren't inherited).
Although Groovy lets you access private fields easier than Java reflection, it still can't access fields which aren't exist.

Comment: As I mentioned these classes are Java not Groovy so no setter here

Comment: Still, private fields aren't inherited. I'll redact my answer, but the main message is the same: private fields aren't inherited.

Comment: I was looking for some construction in which I could say directly I'm interested in a field from super class: like user.@super.id or something like that. Equivalent of user.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredField()

Comment: only reflection, then.

Answer (score 0):

Let me revive this question as I'm going through a similar thing recently. Here are a few thoughts...

As it's needed for tests perhaps a comparison by equals would do instead of checking/setting fields directly?

Pattern worth considering if the alternative is de-encapsulation. I mean, if there is no need to touch these fields in prod code ideally they shouldn't need being touched in tests either.

`Entity` would have own fields based `equals` and `hashCode` implemented.
Lombok's `@EqualsAndHashCode` annotation can help with reducing the boilerplate.

Test goes then like `expect: new Entity(id) == new Entity(id)` (assuming there is such constructor).

If equality is not the way to go package scope might give better encapsulation with an appropriate package structure (main/src/java):

```
package foo.bar

public class Entity {
    Long id
}
```

Control over the `id` access is more flexible now and independent from the test code. While `User extends Entity` can have no access to the `id` if placed in a different package, the test code can have a class accessing it, like for example (src/test/groovy):

```
package foo.bar

class EntityAccess {
    private final Entity entity

    EntityAccess(Entity entity) {
        this.entity = entity
    }

    static EntityAccess access(Entity entity) {
        new EntityAccess(entity)
    }

    Long getId() {
        entity.id
    }

    void setId(Long id) {
        entity.id = id
    }
}
```

I'm sure the boilerplate can be reduced with some fancy Groovy AST annotations. The point is prod code can keep the fields hidden while in tests, with a static import for `EntityAccess.access`, a field can be accessed without any Groovy hax0rs:

`given: access(entity).id = 5` to set or `expect: access(entity).id == 5` to assert on entity's id.

If possible though, I would've rather kept both the `Entity` and `User` immutable and tested by equality without altering the objects state.